# Frequent deadlock when using PFUser.CurrentUser in multiple threads

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I know there have been many similar issues opened in the past, but I haven't run into this one until very recently.

The deadlock only occurs when my app is launching. I've tried commenting out dozens of lines of code that the stacktrace points to, but the problem doesn't go away. If anyone knows a way to avoid this, that would be awesome. My app depends on being able to run multiple queries on launch, so I can't just get rid of the functionality that's causing the problem.

Here is a partial stacktrace: 
[image]

[image]

I'm not really sure what the problem is, but it definitely has to do with currentUser. Based on previous problems that people have had, it may also be an issue with Facebook login. Either way, this is a really frustrating problem, and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

I am using Parse 1.8.0, ParseUI 1.1.5, and ParseFacebookUtils 1.8.0.1

I will post more details if someone can point me in the right direction of where to look.

**Edit**

Here is a stack trace from a different run. I think the problem has something to do with Facebook authenticating currentUser while I am accessing currentUser elsewhere

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we see the stack trace for the other blocking thread ?

Comment: @deadbeef I added screenshots from a different run of the app with the stacktrace of the other problem thread